# Can't parse sentence with 「へったくれもない」

Tags: grammar, word-choice, jlpt

In my JLPT textbook, they have this sentence:

> 自分{じぶん}のない者{もの}に表現{ひょうげん}もへったくれもない。

The book provides a translation, which is this:

> You can't talk about expression if you have none (of your own ideas).

*(The "of your own ideas" part is built on the context from the previous paragraph.)*

I'm having trouble seeing how we get to that translation, partly because I'm not sure about the use of `へったくれもない`. According to my dictionary, `へったくれ` is an expression meaning "to be damned", as in, "to heck with it". So I would understand the sentence if it just ended there, but there's a `もない` as well, which would seem to reverse that, meaning, in my mind, that you *can't* discount self expression from someone without ideas.

Or maybe I'm not parsing it right, and it's not `へったくれ`, but the `へる` is something else, like `減る`.

I don't know. It just confuses me. How do the parts of the sentence combine to end up with the translation given?

Comment: which book is it?

Answer (score 3):

The common idiomatic form of hettakure is `～もへったくれも<negative>`. The negative is often just `nai`, but it can also be `V-nai` or even `aru mono ka` (=nai).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the common form of the phrase is. However, it's exact meaning is still unclear to me, so I'm still unable to parse the example sentence.

Comment: hettakure means that something is boring, useless, of no value. Daijirin has the following illustrative example: 規則もへったくれもあるか: is there anything as useless as rules? ie, there is nothing as useless as rules. If you wish to give it a more colloquial translation, "damn the rules" or " to hell with the rules".

Comment: Thanks for defining the term a little clearer. Based on that, would another way of translating the sentence in the question be, "If you don't have (your own ideas), then to hell with your expressions." ...?