# Need help understanding what 卑怯もくそもあるか means

Tags: meaning, words, expressions

I get that it's kinda of slangy, but I'm having issues wrapping my head around it.

The full sentence was ケンカに卑怯もクソもあるかと言ったのは誰だったかな

Comment: This is similar in usage: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11622/43676

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76339/5010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general construct:

```
(something) もクソもない
```

means that `(something)` isn't even a sensible topic (in the given certain context). There are a number of possible reasons: there is something to be address in prior to a problem; it is completely out of context; someone asked about a certain quality (adjective) of something that has no resemblance of it; etc.

As an example, `戦うもクソもない` could be used in any situation when fighting is completely out of context/nonsensical: because the opponent is so much stronger and you stand no chance; because the other party isn't an enemy and fighting them would be insane; because there is something much more important to be done at the moment than fighting; etc.

Likewise, `喧嘩に卑怯もクソもあるか` could be said when:

- Someone has been accused of doing something cheap/coward (卑怯)
- That someone believes that in the given context (喧嘩), being 卑怯 or not is not important, or that you can't be 卑怯 (e.g. because there are no rules)

Comment: I get it now! Thank you so much